# shared library not found even with ld.so.conf updated

Tags: linux, debian, libraries, arm, dynamic-linking

```
$ sudo ldconfig -v|grep libOpenNI
355: libOpenNI2.so -> libOpenNI2.so
```

but when I am executing the program I'm getting

```
./SimpleRead: error while loading shared libraries: libOpenNI2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Strange?!!

Comment: @JosephR. it's pre-compiled binary for ARM

Comment: Looks like the library is compiled for a different ABI. Please post the output of `file /path/to/libOpenNI2.so ./SimpleRead` and `ldd /path/to/libOpenNI2.so SimpleRead`. Which arm architecture variant is this, and how was `SimpleRead` compiled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run the command `ldd ./SimpleRead` you can see more details on which dynamic libraries your executable is attempting to use. Additionally you can see where it's looking for on the system to find these dynamic libraries (.so files).

#### Example

```
$ ldd /bin/ls
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffff6dff000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00000034e8e00000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00000034e8a00000)
    libcap.so.2 => /lib64/libcap.so.2 (0x0000003d6fe00000)
    libacl.so.1 => /lib64/libacl.so.1 (0x00000034fae00000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00000034e7200000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00000034e7a00000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00000034e6e00000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00000034e7e00000)
    libattr.so.1 => /lib64/libattr.so.1 (0x00000034f7600000)
```

#### References

- [Static, Shared Dynamic and Loadable Linux Libraries](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html)